# Why wouldn't margins collapse into outer paddings?

Tags: html

I've read about margin collapsing, and think I have a good grasp on it, but I haven't found any mention of margin collapsing into outer paddings, what I mean by this is:

```css
.element {
  background: blue;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.container {
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">A</div>
  <div class="element">B</div>
</div>
```

I'm not very experienced in CSS, so the way I read it is:

*container wants to have a padding (inner space) of 20px, and elements want's to have 20 pixels around it (vertically)*.

The first elements only needs to be 20px from the top to satisfy both, but instead it's at 40px (container's padding + element's margin). I'm starting to believe that my expectation is wrong, but wouldn't this make sense? Is there a setting to "trigger" this behavior?

I know `.element:first-of-type { margin-top: 0px }` and `.element:last-of-type { margin-bottom: 0px }` would achieve the result I want visually, but semantically I would now have three types of elements.

Comment: Because that's how the spec was written and it hasn't been changed since. I personally think it would be a really bad idea and it would create a lot of problems and confusion. Considering all aspects and implications, it's safe to assume margins will never collapse into paddings in HTML. And, BTW, this has absolutely nothing to do with CSS. `margin` and `padding` have been around from before CSS was invented.

Comment: Being the last of type or the first of type does not change the type of the element. It's a fact which is true for the respective elements. Semantically you only have one type. `:last-of-type` and `:first-of-type` are just handy CSS methods to style those elements differently than the rest of the collection, because it's often useful to be able to. Ultimately, CSS is a set of conventions. The more you know, the easier it is to get the results you want using the properties you can change. The question is not ***"Why... ?"***, but ***"How...?"***.

Comment: Nothing to do with CSS is a bit extreme: every document under the _w3.org_ domain lists margin under CS. Semantically you have 3 distinct elements with distinct styles applied. I'm more interested in the **"Why"**, the _How_ is very simple in this case.

Comment: My question is about the expected behavior of two CSS properties interacting. Why they interact the way they do is a programming question.  I'm hoping for an answer that points me to the right place to learn why my expectation was wrong and what's the best way to read the interaction between these two properties. I don't know the history of HTML and CSS, but when I search it this is what comes up, under CSS: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-margin-right